How do we make Storybook 7.x/8.x work with a templating engine like Handlebars in 2024?
I've been trying to get the Vanilla HTML version of Storybook to work with something like Handlebars so that I don't have to copy and paste around chunks of HTML when building Atomic components.
(I want to be able to compose the larger components with the smaller ones like one would do in something like Vue, but with Vanilla HTML)
I've had no success. I have not been able to find a more dev/user friendly way of "componentizing" HTML for re-use in Storybook.
Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions for modern(v7/v8) Storybook?
